# Qt background task touch event

Tags: qt, background, symbian, textinput, touch-event

I have a Symbian Qt "background" app that displays a button type thing using CWindowDrawer derived from CActive that is visible on top of everything. I want it to be visible when the a textinput is active or the virtual keyboard is visible, preferably when a textinput is active because some phones have a hardware keyboard. When it is visible I want it to receive all touch positions as to determine if it is being pressed without it taking focus and closing the keyboard?

Basically I need a way to determine when a textinput is activated and I need a way to listen for all touch positions from a non qwidget that is also not in focus.

Any help would be appreciated.

PS. This is for Symbian Belle and Symbian C++ is also supported within a Qt application if necessary.